# Why is $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ almost an integer?

Tags: number-theory

The fact that **Ramanujan's Constant** $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ is almost an integer ($262 537 412 640 768 743.99999999999925...$) doesn't seem to be a coincidence, but has to do with the $163$ appearing in it. Can you explain why it's almost-but-not-quite an integer in layman's terms (I'm not a mathematician)?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30787 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4775 are relevant, but let's see somebody try to explain it without saying "modular". ;)

Comment: This is not really the kind of phenomenon with a layman's-terms explanation...

Comment: @Qiaochu, indeed!

Comment: I observed yet another interesting (IMHO) "almost an integer" related to exp(Pi*sqrt(163)) result, which is: sum((1/(exp(Pi*sqrt(163))^k))*(120/(8*k+1)-60/(8*k+4)-30/(8*k+5)-30/(8*k+6)), k = 0 ... infinity) = 94.000000000000000014789449792044364408558923807659819... Regards, Alexander R. Povolotsky

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a terrible question and doesn't fit the model of SE. I'm appalled by the number of upvotes it got. To the OP: please explain what kind of answer you expect from asking why a number is what it is. Also, the **(number theory)** tag absolutely does not belong.

Comment: similar question: "can you explain why $2+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{e^{10\pi}}}$ is almost-but-not-quite an integer?"

Comment: @chharvey The answers below seem to indicate that there *is* a mathematical explanation for why the expression is almost integral.

Comment: @Strants — I'm not saying it can't be answered, I'm just saying "almost" is relative. By that logic, you could argue 10 is "almost" equal to 100 (compared to, for example, $-10^{100}$). And because "almost" is relative, it's not a very good question to ask on math.SE.

Comment: @chharvey: Bullshit. Even despite the excellent answers clearly demonstrating that this nice (and, have to add, for your attitude: "brave") question indeed has merit, you still intentionally ignored the obvious context, just to rant on it, and continued your misguided policing even after Strants's comment, when no-one at their right mind would still compare the statement about that fascinating expression being x.99999999999925, i.e. "almost an integer" to "10 almost being 100", as you did in your comment. To quote you "I'm appalled by the number of upvotes it got". ;)

Comment: In the book Galois Theory for Beginners: A Historical Perspective Page xi (12 of 202) (https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-35/12), via "numeric calculation", it is stated that exp(pi \times sqrt(163)) = 262537412640768744. How is this justified, since it clearly is not an integral quantity?

Comment: @DavidH The footnote admits that it is an approximation and the text calls it an "hypothesis."

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I do not think "why" has a reasonable layman's-terms answer, but let me at least explain "how" with a simpler example of such a numerical coincidence.  If one takes powers of the golden ratio $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ it is not hard to see that they are close to integers.  For example, $\phi^{20} = 15126.999934...$.  One might ask an analogous question about why these numbers are close to integers.  The answer is that

$$\phi^n + \varphi^n = L_n$$

where $L_n$ is the $n^{th}$ [Lucas number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) (an integer), and where $\varphi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ has absolute value less than $1$.  As $n$ gets larger, $\varphi^n$ gets smaller, so $\phi^n$ becomes a better and better approximation to the integer $L_n$.

A similar, but much more complicated, phenomenon is happening here.  The reason $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ is so close to an integer is that it, plus a small error term, gives a special formula for that integer.  But "why" this formula exists is a rather [long and complicated story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication) (as Robin Chapman hints at) and I do not think there is any reasonable way to talk about it in layman's terms.

Comment: For a generalization of the above example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number .

Comment: accepted as answer for explaining how some numbers approach integers, albeit with a completely different example. I understand Rumanujan's Constant is way beyond my understanding of mathematics.

Comment: The above explanation is not correct. The approximation property of powers of the golden ratio are due to the fact that it is a Pisot number, i.e., it is > 1 and all its conjugates have absolute value < 1. While interesting, it has applications to Fourier analysis, the Salem-Zygmund theorem characterizing a class of sets of uniqueness, this is not at all what is going on here.

Comment: @ilan: I never claimed that it was. I claimed that it was *similar* (in that there is a formula for an integer which has a bulk term and a small error term).

Comment: Considering the above answer, there are an infinite number of near-integer numbers that nicely coincide with n/φ where n is a positive integer, and by finding those near-integer numbers you actually are discovering the Fibonacci, Lucas, and other values. For example, 55/φ=33.99..., 89/φ=55.005.., 144/φ=88.997... and so on. The larger the value that aligns with a Lucas, Fibonacci, or other similar n2+n1 progression the closer the value comes to a whole number.

Answer (score 87):

This is quite a challenge to express in "layman's terms", but the
reason is that
$$j\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2}\right)$$
is an integer where $j$ is the [$j$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant). When you substitute
$(1+\sqrt{-163})/2$ into the $q$-expansion (see the wikipedia page)
of $j$, all terms save the first two are small, and the first two equal
$$-\exp(\pi\sqrt{163})+744.$$

The reason that this $j$-value is an integer is due to the quadratic
field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-163})$ having
[class number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_%28number_theory%29) one, or equivalently that all positive-definite
[integer binary quadratic forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form) of discriminant $-163$ are equivalent.

**Added**
I'll try to explain the connection with binary quadratic forms. Consider
a quadratic form
$$Q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$$
with $a$, $b$ and $c$ integers. I'll only consider forms $Q$ which are
*primitive*, so that $a$, $b$ and $c$ have no common factor $ > 1$,
and *positive-definite*, that is $a > 0$ and the *discriminant*
$D=b^2-4ac < 0$. There is a notion of equivalence of quadratic forms,
and two primitive positive-definite forms $Q$ and $Q'(x,y)=a'x^2+b'xy+c'y^2$
(necessarily also of discriminant $D$) are equivalent if and only if
$$j\left(\frac{b+\sqrt{-D}}{2a}\right)
=j\left(\frac{b'+\sqrt{-D}}{2a'}\right).$$
For each possible discriminant there are only finitely many equivalence
classes. Thus we get a finite set of $j$-values for each discriminant, and
the big theorem is that they are the solutions of a monic algebraic equation
with integer coefficients. When there is only one class the equation has the
form $x-k=0$ where $x$ is an integer, and the $j$-value must be an integer.

My recommended reference for this is David Cox's book
[Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pSMlAQAAIAAJ&q=cox+primes&dq=cox+primes&hl=en&ei=0E2OTIKIHZOCswb3ysmAAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAA). But these results appear towards
the end of this 350-page book.

Comment: Related to this are the Heegner numbers: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeegnerNumber.html

Comment: Worth adding that $163$ is the largest number having this property. That $e^{\pi\sqrt{43}}$ is within $10^{-3}$ of an integer, $e^{\pi\sqrt{67}}$ is with $10^{-6}$ if an integer, but $163$ gets us within $10^{-12}$ of an integer. The values smaller than $43$ don't get us appreciably close to integer values, however.\

Answer (score 7):

I know it's super late but in case anyone has this question in the future, Richard Borcherds made a really digestible video on it in 2020: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9k_QmZbwX8&list=PLar4u0v66vIodqt3KSZPsYyuULD5meoAo&index=85

Answer (score 5):

As QY pointed out this cannot be explained in layman terms: Here are the papers which you would like to see: [www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/ramanujanday.pdf](http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/ramanujanday.pdf)

http://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/episq163.pdf

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.