# Curious 123456789 x 8 + 9 = 987654321

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was recently asked why the following results holds

\begin{align}
1 \times 8 + 1 &= 9 \\
12 \times 8 + 2 & = 98 \\
123 \times 8 + 3 & = 987 \\
1234 \times 8 + 4 & = 9876 \\
12345 \times 8 + 5 & = 98765 \\
123456 \times 8 + 6 & = 987654 \\
1234567 \times 8 + 7 & = 9876543 \\
12345678 \times 8 + 8 & = 98765432 \\
123456789 \times 8 + 9 & = 987654321. \\
\end{align}

I honestly had some trouble giving my friend an answer.  After filling a writing block with pencil equations, I found a hint in a number theory book for a similar result and used the fact that any number can be represented as $N = a_n10^n+a_{n-1}10^{n-1}+\ldots a_110 + a_0$ and playing around with the above equations, one can see algebraically why this holds.

From my notes, I see that I showed that

$$(10-2)(1 \cdot 10^{n-1} + 2 \cdot 10^{n-2} + \ldots + n \cdot 10^0) + n = $$
$$(10-1)10^{n-1} + (10-2)10^{n-2} + \ldots (10-n)10^0.$$.

This is not very satisfactory.  I know from number theory, that there is a result $10 \equiv 1 \pmod9$ and I have seen some interesting consequences of it.  Can this result be used to show why the 'pyramid' holds?  Something similar perhaps?

Comment: Related ; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396135/why-is-987654321-123456789-8-0000000729 ?

Comment: Why is that not satisfactory, again?

Comment: Probably he means *satisfying*, which I would agree with.

Comment: Check out this link -> https://www.quora.com/Why-does-123456789-x-8-+-9-987654321