# pseudo-identities which are not exact but the error is very small

Tags: inequality, rounding-error

i would like to know more example of pseudo identities.. things that there are not equal but the error is about $ 0.01 $

for example $$ \pi ^{4} +\pi ^{5} =e^{6} $$

the error term is about $ 10^{-5} $

where can i see more of this amazing pseudo identities ? :D thanks

Comment: [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1047/) has a list of some good ones.  [And this one](https://xkcd.com/217/).

Comment: And, from the title text of that last one,
$$
\pi = \sqrt[4]{9^2 + \frac{19^2}{22}}
$$

Comment: Also, from an [April fools article in Scientific American](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanConstant.html): 
$$
e^{\pi \sqrt{163}} = 640320^3 + 744
$$

Comment: $e^{i\pi} + 1 \approx 0.01$.

Comment: Wikipedia has a whole page about them: [Mathematical coincidences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence)

Comment: Actually, you have found [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470998/why-mathrm-e-sqrt27-pi-is-almost-an-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1) yourself.

Comment: Also on wikipedia: [Almost integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer).

Comment: @Michael Nice one!

Answer (score 4):

The number
$$\alpha:={1\over10}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-(n/10)^2}$$
is $\>\approx\sqrt{\pi}$ with an accuracy of more than $400$ decimal places, but is $\ne\sqrt{\pi}$. This has to do with Jacobi's Theta-transform
$$\vartheta(x):=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x}={1\over\sqrt{x}}\vartheta\left({1\over x}\right)\ .$$

Comment: I take it that this works for any k, not just 10, getting more accurate as k increases, i.e.: $\sqrt{\pi}\approx\frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(n/k)^2}$

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples given here at MSE. One of my favourites is that
$$
e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}=262 537 412 640 768 743.99999999999925
$$
is very close to an integer, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/why-is-e-pi-sqrt163-almost-an-integer). This has some serious number theoretical background, as is explained, and generalised, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30787/why-is-e-pi-sqrt232-an-almost-integer).