# Is there a straight forward way to prove that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{31} > 3$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, harmonic-numbers

Using brute force, it is straight forward to calculate that  $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{31} > 3$

Is there a more elegant way to demonstrate this?

What if I want to find the smallest $n$ such that $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} > 4$

Is there a standard way to solve for $n$ without using brute force?

Comment: Something like say $\lceil e^{N+1-\gamma}+\frac12\rceil $?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first inequation can be written $H_{31}>4$, where $H_n= 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}$

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.2524.pdf) (Guo, B.-N. and Qi, F., “Sharp inequalities for the psi function and harmonic numbers”; theorem 5) this bound is proved:

$$ \ln\left(n+\frac12\right)+\gamma \le  H_n \le \ln(n + e^{1-\gamma}-1)+\gamma \tag{1}$$

where $\gamma$ is the [Euler Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) ( $\approx 0.577215664901532$).
This bound is much sharper than the usual ones like $\ln(n+1) <  H_n < \ln(n+1)+1$ , which would be useless here.

We get

$$H_{31} \ge  4.02720321 \cdots$$

and

$$H_{30} \le 3.99580\cdots$$

which is enough for our purpose.

This is not very elegant, probably, but I doubt that you can find something much better (and for general $n$)

The bound is so remarkably tight (the true value is   $H_{31}=4.027245195\cdots$) that we can use it for finding the cutting point for larger values (up to 12 at least), except for 6 where it cannot decide between 226 and 227.

Comment: This bound is incredibly close to the actual sum. Nice job!

Comment: @LaarsHelenius That is to be expected, as the error term is $<\frac{1}{2n}$

Answer (score 3):

Claim: $$\sum_{i=1}^{3^n}\frac{1}{i} \geq \frac{7}{6}+\frac{2}{3}n$$ 
whenever $n\geq2$.

Proof: By Mathematical Induction.

Take $n=3$, then instantly $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{27}\geq \frac{7}{6}+2 >  3$.

Hope this is not a brutal way and this can be easily generalized.

Answer (score 1):

[I'll have time later to expand on this answer but here's my initial thought]

This idea comes from a proof for proving the [harmonic series diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence).

Namely, that $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2^k} \frac{1}{n} \geq 1 + \frac{k}{2}. $$

So you can at least put an upper bound on whatever number you want to exceed by rounding appropriately for the value of $k$.

Comment: Unfortunately if you want the sum to exceed $5=1+\frac{8}{2}$, this bound says it suffices to sum $2^8=256$ terms - way more than the $83$ that are actually needed.

Comment: @kccu True, the bound is slovenly. But that's why I prefaced it as just a bound for now. I was inclined to later take the direction that the user "leonbloy" pursued below. This bound is just nice because it falls out immediately from the direction of proving the Harmonic series diverges. No experience with logarithms/digamma needed, only fractions!

Answer (score 1):

The number $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is the $n$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). The harmonic series grows extremely slowly. You are looking at $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k}=H_n-1$. So your question amounts to "what is the smallest harmonic number $>5$?" By brute force I've found it's $H_{83}$, so you have to add $\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{83}$ to get something bigger than $4$.

If you're just interested in a few of these numbers, there's a list [here](http://oeis.org/A002387).

The [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) is related to the harmonic numbers: $\psi(n)=H_{n-1}-\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. If you have a way to compute values of the digamma function, you could approximately find the correct value of $n$ and then check it by brute force. I'm not sure of a more elegant or exact approach.

Answer (score 1):

[BBP-type formulas](http://oeis.org/A165132) for $\log(3)$ and $\log(7)$ in base $3$

$$\log(3)=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{9}{2k+1}+\frac{1}{2k+2}\right)\frac{1}{9^{k}}$$

$$\log(7)=\frac{1}{3^5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{405}{6k+1}+\frac{81}{6k+2}+\frac{72}{6k+3}+\frac{9}{6k+4}+\frac{5}{6k+5}\right)\frac{1}{3^{6k}}$$

give lower bounds

$$\log(3)>\left(9+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{1}{9}+\left(\frac{9}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)\frac{1}{81}=\frac{355}{324}$$

and
$$\log(7)>\left(405+\frac{81}{2}+\frac{72}{3}+\frac{9}{4}+\frac{5}{5}\right)\frac{1}{3^5}=\frac{1891}{972}$$

From [Series and integrals for inequalities and approximations to $\log(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656344/series-and-integrals-for-inequalities-and-approximations-to-logn)
$$\log(2)=\frac{7}{10}-\int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^2}{1+x^2} dx$$

the upper bound

$$\log(2)<\frac{7}{10}$$

is obtained, and also the convergent approximation

$$\gamma>\frac{15}{26}$$

will be useful.

For your particular case $n=31$, the bound 
$$ H_n \ge \log(n+\frac12)+\gamma$$

given by @leonbloy becomes

$$\begin{align}
H_{31} &\ge \log(2·31+1)-\log(2)+\gamma\\
&=2\log(3) + \log(7) - \log(2) + \gamma\\
&>2\frac{355}{324}+\frac{1891}{972}-\frac{7}{10}+\frac{15}{26}=\frac{253589}{63180}\\
&=4+\frac{869}{63180} \gt 4
\end{align}$$

which proves $H_{31}>4$.

To compute the smallest $n$ such that $H_n$ exceeds an integer $N$,

$$log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\gamma>N$$
$$log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)>N-\gamma$$
$$n+\frac{1}{2}>e^{N-\gamma}$$
$$n>e^{N-\gamma}-\frac{1}{2}$$

so

$$n=\lceil e^{N-\gamma}-\frac{1}{2}\rceil$$

The PARI code

```
for (N=0,28,print(N," ",ceil(exp(N-Euler)-1/2)))
```

shows that this formula produces the values published in http://oeis.org/A002387, although this does not imply that it agrees forever. The inequality and the formula derived here guarantees exceeding $N$, not doing so with the lowest $n$ possible, as in the OEIS sequence.