# Value of $n$ required for harmonic series to cross a certain value.

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

what is the value of $n$ so that the partial sum $S_n$ of the harmonic series ie $\sum _1 ^n \frac{1}{x} \geq y$ where $y$ is a natural number.
I started with $2,3$ and got answers for $n$ as $4,11$. But for $5$ its $83$. Seeing this I have a strong belief that there's a formula which can be used to calculate $n$ quickly. Also if there is formula can it be used for irrational ,rational numbers. Note i tried integration but it obviously doesn't work for small $y$.

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2265224/134791), to compute the smallest $n$ such that $H_n$ exceeds an integer $N$,

$$log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\gamma>N$$
$$log\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)>N-\gamma$$
$$n+\frac{1}{2}>e^{N-\gamma}$$
$$n>e^{N-\gamma}-\frac{1}{2}$$

so

$$n=\lceil e^{N-\gamma}-\frac{1}{2}\rceil$$

Answer (score 0):

The $n$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_n$ behaves like $\log(n)+\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). 
It follows that $H_n=N$ has a solution close to $n=\exp\left(N-\gamma\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown by induction that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac1{k} > \frac{n}{2}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{k=1}^{4^n}\frac1{k} > n$$

This isn't optimal but nice.