# Why is in Matlab exp(pi * sqrt(163)/3) - 640320 = -2.3283e-10

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

Why is in Matlab

$$
e^{\pi\cdot\frac{\sqrt{163}}{3}} - 640320 = -2.3283 * 10^{-10}
$$

```
exp(pi * sqrt(163)/3) - 640320
ans =-2.3283e-10
```

I know that it does have something to do with IEEE754, but I can't figure exactly out why.

```
exp(pi*sqrt(163)/3) = 640320,
```

so the result should be 0.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: The correct value is by the way $$6.04863735049016039471741818818539475771485760366591819465222 E-10$$

Comment: without the "/3" it has something to do with the Heegner-numbers , no idea why it is an almost integer also with this division.

Comment: @Peter, the result term exp(pi*sqrt(163)/3) is 640320, so the result should actually be 0. Sorry if it was unclear, I edited my quesiton.

Comment: Why do you think that the expression is exactly an integer ? This is not the case. It is an almost-integer , very near to an integer , but not an integer. Maybe you computed it with a calculator with insufficient accuracy,

Comment: $$e^{\pi\cdot \frac{\sqrt{163}}{3}}\simeq 640320.000000000604863735049036$$

Comment: $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ is Ramanujan's constant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, that expression is *not* an integer, but very close to an integer $640320$. In fact, as @Peter mentioned, this is related to some deep theory of modular $j$-functions and Heegner numbers, e.g. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#The_q-expansion_and_moonshine) and [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/why-is-e-pi-sqrt163-almost-an-integer#:%7E:text=The%20fact%20that%20Ramanujan%27s%20Constant,the%20163%20appearing%20in%20it.). Anyway, the main reason is that we have

$$
e^{\pi \sqrt{163}} \approx 640320^3 + 744
$$

with an error $< 10^{-12}$, so

$$
e^{\frac{\pi\sqrt{163}}{3}} \approx (640320^3 + 744)^{1/3} = 640320 \cdot \left(1 + \frac{744}{640320^3}\right)^{1/3} \approx 644320
$$

where the last approximation is due to

$$
\left(1 + \frac{744}{640320^3}\right)^{1/3} \approx (1 + 3 \cdot 10^{-15})^{1/3} \approx 1 + 10^{-15}.
$$

Comment: Great answer (+1)